# Analysis Services database returns oddly formatted numbers on MDX queries

Tags: internationalization, formatting, ssas

I have a SQL Server 2008 Database server hosting two Analysis services databases. When from the same machine I run a MDX query in SSMS against both of these DBs (e.g. SELECT { [Gender].[M], [Gender].[W] } on 0, { [Area].[Town].[3101000], [Area].[Town].[3152007] } on 1 FROM [Population] WHERE ([Time].[Years].[2005], [Population]) the one query returns a table consisting of floating number values formatted like 123,23 while the other DB returns floating numbers formatted like 123.23

In Visual Studio, measures from both projects are defined as double values, in the source databases values are taken from NUMERIC columns.

I populated these two DBs from two different relational databases (both however share the same collation settings) and also the Visual studio solutions used to deploy the AS DBs were different (still for the second one I just took a copy of my first vs solution and basically only removed some unnecessary dimensions and cubes).

My question is: What are the suspects to look for that can cause the difference in the formatting of MDX results?

- I already checked the collation settings of the source DBs which seem to be identical
- I checked for language settings in the AS DB but did not find any suitable setting (did I maybe oversee something)
- I checked the FormatString properties in the cubes which were unset in both solutions

Any further ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything in the "Calculations" tab of the cube in VS/BIDS? You can override format strings for measures there.

Also, are you setting language in the connection string to SSAS? This is possible, and is used by clients to automatically format numbers in the locale of the user. Seems unlikely if you're  running this in in SSMS but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Thanks Meff, and sorry for requiring so much time for an answer. I checked the calculations tab and did not find anything there (except for the default CALCULATE expression). I'm also pretty sure to not have any weird language settings since we are talking about two AS databases residing on the same server, sharing the same connection in SSMS.

Comment: @David There is a "Language" property of the cube, if you open the cube in VS, the leftmost tab (Cube Structure) and highlight the cube on the left-upper pane, there is a Language element in the properties window. Also, in Management Studio, Right-Click the cube and create as XMLA to a new window. In that window, search for "language" and see if anything looks off (Dimensions also have languages..).

Comment: There is indeed a difference in the language definition of both cube. In the visual studio properties however, language properties are empty for both cubes. Setting the desired language in the wrong formatted cube solved this problem for me, still I'm curious there must be an overriding property that affects the cubes default behaviour when language is unset. Any idea what this property could be?

Comment: @David, sorry I don't know - If I had to guess I'd expect it to use the default locale of the connection. The super-default is 1033 I think, US-English, so it's odd you're getting Central-European formatting - Unless you're a Central-European developer? Glad you got your bug fixed at least :)